# React error: Can't import the named export 'translate' (imported as 'translate') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

Tags: reactjs, api, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to connect a google translate api to my react app. (name of the library: google-translate-api-x)
It works in a normal node script but it throws the error in react:

Can't import the named export 'translate' (imported as 'translate') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

According to the documentation it should work normally in the browser.

The code:
"""
`import { translate, Translator, singleTranslate, getBatchInitData, batchTranslate, languages, isSupported, getCode } from 'google-translate-api-x';

```
async function dummy(){
const res = await translate('Translating something ', {to: 'en'});
console.log(res.text); 
}`
```

"""

I've created the react app using the "create-react-app".

It's probably something simple but I'm a bit lost with react configuration.. :P
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IT seems the problem was with configuration - I ve redone the react setup with webpack manually and the library imported alright.